# How to get an enum constant from the first matching enum type

Tags: java, generics, enums

Note: this question is more about generics than it is about enums.

I have few enum types, all implementing a common interface `IEffect`.

For example

```
enum ElementalEffect implements IEffect {
    FIRE, WATER;
}
enum CombatEffect implements IEffect {
    PARALYSIS, SLEEP;
}
```

I would like to parse a config-file, that should add effects to a weapon. For that I have to resolve a given name to one of the effects. To keep it simple to maintain, I thought of writing a method like this (mostly pseudo-code, this does not compile. In fact the point of the question is how to make this compile):

```
IEffect resolveEffectName(String name, Class... clazzes) {
    for(Class clazz : clazzes) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException) { /* ignore, try next class */}
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching effect found for " + name);
}
// resolveEffectName(readNameFromFile, ElementalEffect.class, CombatEffect.class);
```

Now the problem I have is that I can't figure out how to write that method without the compiler telling me

> The method `valueOf(Class<T>, String)` in the type Enum is not applicable for the arguments ...

---

People saying it should be

```
private static ICombatEffectType getFirstResolved(String name, Class<? extends Enum<?>>... classes) {
    for (Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz : classes) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is not working. Feel free to try it (if you don't believe me).

> The method `valueOf(Class<T>, String)` in the type Enum is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<capture#6-of ? extends Enum<?>>, String)`

Comment: `Class<? extends Enum<?>>... clazzes`

Comment: This does not work, because the captures for the `?` in Class and the one for the nested Enum are different but have to be the same to be able to call Enum.valueOf

Comment: Hm, true. But consider that if you're having trouble writing this in a type-safe way then you might just need to find a completely different approach.

Comment: I assume you text file contains effect names and that this names are unique over all the enums. In that case I'd put all the effects in a `Map<String,IEffect>` and sipmly get the named effect by `effectMap.get(name)` - too simple?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle the thing is that there are multiple effect classes, ~7, and not all items can use all effects. So it wouldn't be one map, but up to 2**7 = 128 maps, which is not feasable to do. Maybe I can have multiple views of an underlying map, containing all mappings, or check seperatly. Either way this was simpler upfront

Comment: @WorldSEnder what about a more OO like approach? The classes could hold a list of IEffects they can hold (which could also be configured in a txt file and filled into the "class" objects at  startup using the same Map)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this fluently, if that's your style:

```
class FluentGetter {
  private final String name;
  private IEffect found;

  FluentGetter(String name) { this.name = name; }

  <T extends Enum<T> & IEffect> FluentGetter search(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (found == null) { // If you've already found something, don't overwrite that.
      try {
        found = Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
    }
    return this;
  }

  IEffect get() {
    return found;  // + check if it's null, if you want.
  }
}
```

Then:

```
IEffect effect =
    new FluentGetter(name)
        .search(ElementalEffect.class)
        .search(CombatEffect.class)
        .get();
```

This avoids the problem of the generic bounds on the array of classes by having separate method calls for each.

Pretty sure I wouldn't use this myself; just tossing it out as an option.

Comment: I like it. As only some effect-classes of all possible ones will be enabled for a specific *item type*, this makes searching only a few of them really easy

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a map of names to enum constants, which you can easily make using streams:

```
private static final Map<String, IEffect> constants
    = Stream.of(ElementalEffect.values(), CombatEffect.values())
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Enum::name, Function.identity()));

IEffect resolveEffectName(String name) {
    if(!constants.containsKey(name))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching effect found for " + name);

    return constants.get(name);
}
```

Comment: Surely you can then only pass in a single value in `clazzes`?

Comment: @AndyTurner You're right, I thought array covariance would be enough there. hmm, now I'm just confusing myself.

Comment: The first way does not work, as it requires the same type-bound on every enum-class. But you are right about your second point, I should precompute the mapping and normalize the names

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make everything work without warnings using a wrapper class:

```
private static class Wrapper<T extends Enum<T> & IEffect> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public Wrapper(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public IEffect resolveName(String name) {
        return Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
    }
}
private static IEffect getFirstResolved(String name, Wrapper<?>... clazzes) {
    for (Wrapper<?> clazz : clazzes) {
        try {
            return clazz.resolveName(name);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum has a member " + name);
}

// Example call
ICombatEffectType elemental = getFirstResolved(
            type,
            new Wrapper<>(ElementalType.class),
            new Wrapper<>(StatusEffect.class));
```

Comment: Good way but I think that the wrapper is not helpful. You should not have warning problems if you type correctly and even if you had that, it's a pity to complexify your design to handle that

Comment: What the wrapper does is ensure the compiler that in `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` the two anonymous captures are the same (needed to be able to call Enum#valueOf with that class)

Answer (score 0):

This should compile (with warnings), using your first method:

```
return (IEffect) Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) clazz, name);
```